# Cordova/Ionic app, prevent redirecting the main WebView

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a Cordova/Ionic app that uses a 3rd party JS lib that is used for a customer feedback chat window. When the chat is opened, it redirects the whole app's webview, I want to avoid this.

The JS lib is injected into the page through a dynamic `<script>` tag. I can't mess with it -- or don't want to. 
The chat window can be opened by an API-call. There's no API function to get the URL that will be opened.

The API call redirects the whole browser app. I want to show the new page in the external browser or preferably in an `<iframe>`

The page works differently in Chrome dev and in mobile, e.g. Safari. This might be partially because of the lib too.

I have tried:

- `<iframe>`. Not works, redirects the whole page. How can I prevent it?
- `window.onbeforeunload`: Ain't fires in iOS.
- `<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true/false" />` in `config.xml`

What are your suggestions? There must be something I'm missing...

Comment: If you include and call the API script inside the iframe tag, it shouldn't be able to redirect the host window to anywhere.

Comment: as you don't have control over the script, there is nothing you can do

Comment: @sanfor: That's the `<iframe>` option.